# why Cannot read properties of null (reading '0') happens when passing total from one to another page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I somehow made that it pass values from product page to checkout page and calculate total,now I need that it pass total from checkout page to index page which is in this case payment page,I tried to make something basic but it does not display total and subtotal of checkout page in payment page and in console says : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')
at index.html:41:79

this is code of product page

```
<section id="prodetails" class="section-p1">
            <div class="productcontainer" id="enjoy">
                <div class="single-pro-image">
                  <img src="../data/high.png"  width="100%" id="product-image" class="product-img">
                </div>
            
                <div class="single-pro-details" action="C:\s\starter-ruby\client\checkout.html">
                  <h4 class="product-title" id="title">Enjoy</h4>
                  <h2 id="price" class="price">$20</h2>
                  <h3>Select Licence</h3>
                  <select id="select" class="licence">
                    <option>MP3</option>
                    <option>Tagged Wav</option>
                    <option>Un-Tagged Wav</option>
                    <option>Stems</option>
                    <option>Exlusive</option>
                  </select>
    
                    <script>
                      let select = document.getElementById('select');
                      let price = document.getElementById('price');
    
                      // Prices
                      let prices = {
                        "MP3": '$20',
                        "Tagged Wav": '$27',
                        "Un-Tagged Wav": '$30',
                        "Stems": '$120',
                        "Exlusive": '$300'
                      }
    
                      // When the value of select changes, this event listener fires and changes the text content of price to the coresponding value from the prices object
                      select.addEventListener('change', () => {
                        price.textContent = prices[select.value];
                      });
                    </script>
                    <button class="add-cart">Add To Cart <i class='bx bx-cart-add add-cart'></i></button>
                    <h4>Product Details</h4>
                    <span>Lil Tjay x Trap Type Beat - "Enjoy" in key D# Minor and 160 BPM,It has vibe of Lil Tjay , Pop Smoke and more , Prices are great for this type of beat;Tagged Mastered MP3 for $25,$27 for Tagged Unmastered Wav,$30 for Untagged unmastered Wav,$70 for Stems and $120 for Exlusive</span>
                </div>
                <div id="audio">
                    <audio controls style="width:100%;" id="audio-clip">
                        <source src="Audio/Enjoy 160 x D sharp minor.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
                    </audio>
                </div>
              </section> 

              <script>
                var selectedItems = [];
  const addToCartButton = document.querySelector('.add-cart');

  if (addToCartButton) {
    addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const productTitle = document.querySelector('#title').textContent;
      const productPrice = document.querySelector('#price').textContent;
      const selectedLicense = document.querySelector('#select').value;
      const productImage = document.getElementById('product-image');
      const ImageSrc = productImage.src;
      const audioElement = document.getElementById('audio-clip');
      const audioSrc = audioElement.src;

      const cartItem = {
        title: productTitle,
        price: productPrice,
        license: selectedLicense,
        image: ImageSrc,
        audio: audioSrc
      };

      let selectedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedItems')) || [];

      // Check if the item already exists in the cart
      let existingItemIndex = selectedItems.findIndex(item => item.title === productTitle && item.license === selectedLicense);

      if (existingItemIndex > -1) {
        // If the item already exists, update the license
        selectedItems[existingItemIndex].license = selectedLicense;
      } else {
        // If the item doesn't exist, add it to the cart
        selectedItems.push(cartItem);
      }

      console.log(selectedItems);

      localStorage.setItem('selectedItems', JSON.stringify(selectedItems));
    });
  }
</script>
```

this is my checkout page

```
  <h2 style="text-align:center;">Checkout</h2>
  <div id="product-items">
    <p style="text-align:center;"><span id="added-products"></p>
    <div class="product-container">
      <div class="cart-items"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="clear-button">CLEAR ITEMS - REDIRECT TO HOME</button>
<script>
  document.getElementById("clear-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const cartItemsDiv = document.querySelector(".cart-items");
  cartItemsDiv.innerHTML = ""; // clear the HTML content of the cart-items div
  const subtotalSpan = document.getElementById("subtotal");
  const totalSpan = document.getElementById("total");
  subtotalSpan.innerHTML = "";
  totalSpan.innerHTML = "$0"; // set the total price to $0
  
  localStorage.removeItem("selectedItems"); // remove the selected items from localStorage
  clearCartItems();
});
</script>
  <!--fix the error that how much items in one cart is,e.g if add 2 mp3 and that it does not display that both 2 items
  
  for (var i = 0; i < cartProducts.length; i++) {
        if (cartProducts[i].title === title && cartProducts[i].option === licence) {
            alert('You have already added this product to your cart with the same option.');
            return;
        }
    }
  -->
  </div>

  <div class="total">
    <form action="index.html" class="total">
    <h3 style="text-align:center; display: none;">Subtotal: <br><span id="subtotal"></span></h3>
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">Total: <br><span id="total">$0</span></h3>
    <a href="index.html"><button type="submit" class="buy-btn" style="background-color: rgb(29, 4, 216);">Continue to purchase</button></a>
    <a href="index.html" onclick="alert('You will be redirected to the home page')"><button style="background-color: rgb(216, 4, 4);">Cancel</button></a>
  </div>
</form>
  <!--It does clear but wonder , make that you cant click on button if that function is done-->
</body>
<script>
  const cartItemsDiv = document.querySelector(".cart-items");
  const storedCartItem = localStorage.getItem("selectedItems");  
  let subtotal = 0;

  const continueButton = document.getElementById("buy-btn");
  const clearButton = document.getElementById("clear-button");

  function clearCartItems() {
  // Clear the HTML content of the cart-items div
  const cartItemsDiv = document.querySelector(".cart-items");
  cartItemsDiv.innerHTML = "";

  // Set the subtotal and total to $0
  const subtotalSpan = document.getElementById("subtotal");
  const totalSpan = document.getElementById("total");
  subtotalSpan.innerHTML = "";
  totalSpan.innerHTML = "$0";

  // Remove the selected items from localStorage
  localStorage.removeItem("selectedItems");

  alert("Added items will be cleared.");
  // Change the URL to the index page and prevent going to the checkout page
  window.location.href = "sproduct6.html";
  history.replaceState(null, "", window.location.href);

  // Update the UI
  document.getElementById("added-products").innerHTML = "You have no items in your cart!";
  document.getElementById("buy-btn").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("clear-button").style.display = "none";

   if (cartItemCount == 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("You have no items in your cart. Let's get back to product page.");
      window.location.href = ('sproduct6.html');
    }, 50); // 3 second delay 
    document.getElementById("added-products").innerHTML = "You have no items in your cart!";
    continueButton.style.display = "none";
    clearButton.style.display = "none";
    // Save the visibility state of the buttons
    localStorage.setItem("buttonsVisible", "false");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("added-products").innerHTML = "YOU ADDED THIS PRODUCTS";
  } 
}

if (storedCartItem) {
  const cartItem = JSON.parse(storedCartItem); // Parse the storedCartItem string into an array

  for (let i = 0; i < cartItem.length; i++) {
    const cartItemElement = document.createElement("div");  

    
    cartItemElement.innerHTML = `
        <hr />
        <h3>${cartItem[i].title}</h3>  
        <p>Price: ${cartItem[i].price}</p>
        <p>License: ${cartItem[i].license}</p>
        <img src="${cartItem[i].image}" width='30%'/><br>
        <audio controls style="width:50%;">
          <source src="${cartItem[i].audio}" type="audio/mp3"> 
        </audio>
        `;
    // ADD DELETE OPTION 

    cartItemsDiv.appendChild(cartItemElement);

    const price = Number(cartItem[i].price.replace("$", "")); // Parse price as a number and remove dollar sign
    subtotal += price;
    // MAKE REPLACE TITLE TO YOU HAVE NO ITEMS IN YOUR CART
  }

  const subtotalElement = document.querySelector("#subtotal");
  subtotalElement.textContent = `$${subtotal.toFixed(2)}`;

  const totalElement = document.querySelector("#total");
  const total = subtotal;
  totalElement.textContent = `$${total.toFixed(2)}`;
  const totalPriceInput = document.querySelector("#total_price");
  totalPriceInput.value = total.toFixed(2);
}

function passtotal(){
  var total = document.getElementById('total').value;
  var subtotal = document.getElementById('subtotal').value;
  localStorage.setItem("values", JSON.stringify({total: total, subtotal: subtotal}));
  return false;
}
</script>
</html>
```

and this is my index payment page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Stripe Sample</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A demo of Stripe" />

    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css" />
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script src="./payment.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="sr-root">
      <span id="total"></span>
      <span id="subtotal"></span>
      <div class="sr-main">
        <h1>Pay with a bunch of payment option</h1>

        <form id="payment-form" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    
          <div id="payment-element"></div>
    
          <button>Pay</button><!--Make functional-->
          <!--Make total price hidden and that total of this is same as in checkout and that its connected to ruby-->
          <div id="error-messages"></div>
        </form>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var value = localStorage.getItem("value");
if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = value[0];
} else {
  alert('something went wrong...Can you please try again')
}
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("value")[0];
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So the error comes from the last line of JS in your HTML file where you `localStorage.getItem("value")[0]`. This implies that `localStorage.getItem("value")` returns `null`. i.e. `localStorage` doesn't hold a value for key `value`. This means you are effectively trying to `null[0]`, causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

In the index.js file, you need to parse the JSON

```
<script>
      var getValue = localStorage.getItem("value");
      var value = JSON.parse(getValue);
if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = value[0];
} else {
  alert('something went wrong...Can you please try again')
}
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("value")[0];
    </script>
```

Comment: I pasted that and now it says that alert , it should not have that alert and it should display total

Comment: I tried something different : https://stackoverflow.com/q/76123882/21574220