# why it says : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

So I built that it add product to cart and to specific div in checkout page,now I need to paste total from checkout page to index page which is in this case payment page.I tried something but it still do not display total.
heres product page

```
<section id="prodetails" class="section-p1">
            <div class="productcontainer" id="enjoy">
                <div class="single-pro-image">
                  <img src="../data/high.png"  width="100%" id="product-image" class="product-img">
                </div>
            
                <div class="single-pro-details" action="C:\s\starter-ruby\client\checkout.html">
                  <h4 class="product-title" id="title">Enjoy</h4>
                  <h2 id="price" class="price">$20</h2>
                  <h3>Select Licence</h3>
                  <select id="select" class="licence">
                    <option>MP3</option>
                    <option>Tagged Wav</option>
                    <option>Un-Tagged Wav</option>
                    <option>Stems</option>
                    <option>Exlusive</option>
                  </select>
    
                    <script>
                      let select = document.getElementById('select');
                      let price = document.getElementById('price');
    
                      // Prices
                      let prices = {
                        "MP3": '$20',
                        "Tagged Wav": '$27',
                        "Un-Tagged Wav": '$30',
                        "Stems": '$120',
                        "Exlusive": '$300'
                      }
    
                      // When the value of select changes, this event listener fires and changes the text content of price to the coresponding value from the prices object
                      select.addEventListener('change', () => {
                        price.textContent = prices[select.value];
                      });
                    </script>
                    <button class="add-cart">Add To Cart <i class='bx bx-cart-add add-cart'></i></button>
                    <h4>Product Details</h4>
                    <span>Lil Tjay x Trap Type Beat - "Enjoy" in key D# Minor and 160 BPM,It has vibe of Lil Tjay , Pop Smoke and more , Prices are great for this type of beat;Tagged Mastered MP3 for $25,$27 for Tagged Unmastered Wav,$30 for Untagged unmastered Wav,$70 for Stems and $120 for Exlusive</span>
                </div>
                <div id="audio">
                    <audio controls style="width:100%;" id="audio-clip">
                        <source src="Audio/Enjoy 160 x D sharp minor.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
                    </audio>
                </div>
              </section> 

              <script>
                var selectedItems = [];
  const addToCartButton = document.querySelector('.add-cart');

  if (addToCartButton) {
    addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const productTitle = document.querySelector('#title').textContent;
      const productPrice = document.querySelector('#price').textContent;
      const selectedLicense = document.querySelector('#select').value;
      const productImage = document.getElementById('product-image');
      const ImageSrc = productImage.src;
      const audioElement = document.getElementById('audio-clip');
      const audioSrc = audioElement.src;

      const cartItem = {
        title: productTitle,
        price: productPrice,
        license: selectedLicense,
        image: ImageSrc,
        audio: audioSrc
      };

      let selectedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedItems')) || [];

      // Check if the item already exists in the cart
      let existingItemIndex = selectedItems.findIndex(item => item.title === productTitle && item.license === selectedLicense);

      if (existingItemIndex > -1) {
        // If the item already exists, update the license
        selectedItems[existingItemIndex].license = selectedLicense;
      } else {
        // If the item doesn't exist, add it to the cart
        selectedItems.push(cartItem);
      }

      console.log(selectedItems);

      localStorage.setItem('selectedItems', JSON.stringify(selectedItems));
    });
  }
</script>
```

and heres checkout page

```
  <div class="total">
    <form action="index.html" class="total">
    <h3 style="text-align:center; display: none;">Subtotal: <br><span id="subtotal"></span></h3>
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">Total: <br><span id="total">$0</span></h3>
    <a href="index.html"><button type="submit" class="buy-btn" style="background-color: rgb(29, 4, 216);">Continue to purchase</button></a>
    <a href="index.html" onclick="alert('You will be redirected to the home page')"><button style="background-color: rgb(216, 4, 4);">Cancel</button></a>
  </div>
</form>
  <!--It does clear but wonder , make that you cant click on button if that function is done-->
</body>
<script>
  const cartItemsDiv = document.querySelector(".cart-items");
  const storedCartItem = localStorage.getItem("selectedItems");  
  let subtotal = 0;

  const continueButton = document.getElementById("buy-btn");
  const clearButton = document.getElementById("clear-button");

  function clearCartItems() {
  // Clear the HTML content of the cart-items div
  const cartItemsDiv = document.querySelector(".cart-items");
  cartItemsDiv.innerHTML = "";

  // Set the subtotal and total to $0
  const subtotalSpan = document.getElementById("subtotal");
  const totalSpan = document.getElementById("total");
  subtotalSpan.innerHTML = "";
  totalSpan.innerHTML = "$0";

  // Remove the selected items from localStorage
  localStorage.removeItem("selectedItems");

  alert("Added items will be cleared.");
  // Change the URL to the index page and prevent going to the checkout page
  window.location.href = "sproduct6.html";
  history.replaceState(null, "", window.location.href);

  // Update the UI
  document.getElementById("added-products").innerHTML = "You have no items in your cart!";
  document.getElementById("buy-btn").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("clear-button").style.display = "none";

   if (cartItemCount == 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("You have no items in your cart. Let's get back to product page.");
      window.location.href = ('sproduct6.html');
    }, 50); // 3 second delay 
    document.getElementById("added-products").innerHTML = "You have no items in your cart!";
    continueButton.style.display = "none";
    clearButton.style.display = "none";
    // Save the visibility state of the buttons
    localStorage.setItem("buttonsVisible", "false");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("added-products").innerHTML = "YOU ADDED THIS PRODUCTS";
  } 
}

if (storedCartItem) {
  const cartItem = JSON.parse(storedCartItem); // Parse the storedCartItem string into an array

  for (let i = 0; i < cartItem.length; i++) {
    const cartItemElement = document.createElement("div");  

    
    cartItemElement.innerHTML = `
        <hr />
        <h3>${cartItem[i].title}</h3>  
        <p>Price: ${cartItem[i].price}</p>
        <p>License: ${cartItem[i].license}</p>
        <img src="${cartItem[i].image}" width='30%'/><br>
        <audio controls style="width:50%;">
          <source src="${cartItem[i].audio}" type="audio/mp3"> 
        </audio>
        `;
    // ADD DELETE OPTION 

    cartItemsDiv.appendChild(cartItemElement);

    const price = Number(cartItem[i].price.replace("$", "")); // Parse price as a number and remove dollar sign
    subtotal += price;
    // MAKE REPLACE TITLE TO YOU HAVE NO ITEMS IN YOUR CART
  }

  const subtotalElement = document.querySelector("#subtotal");
  subtotalElement.textContent = `$${subtotal.toFixed(2)}`;

  const totalElement = document.querySelector("#total");
  const total = subtotal;
  totalElement.textContent = `$${total.toFixed(2)}`;
  const totalPriceInput = document.querySelector("#total_price");
  totalPriceInput.value = total.toFixed(2);
}

function passtotal(){
  var total = document.getElementById('total').value;
  var subtotal = document.getElementById('subtotal').value;
  localStorage.setItem("value", total);
  return false;
}
</script>
```

and heres index page where total should display in total span

```
  <body>
    <div class="sr-root">
      <div id="total"></div>
      <div class="sr-main">
        <h1>Pay with a bunch of payment option</h1>

        <form id="payment-form" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    
          <div id="payment-element"></div>
    
          <button>Pay</button><!--Make functional-->
          <!--Make total price hidden and that total of this is same as in checkout and that its connected to ruby-->
          <div id="error-messages"></div>
        </form>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var getValue = localStorage.getItem("value");
      var value = JSON.parse(getValue);
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("value");
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about the error message? Which page does it occur on? Which page is causing it?

Comment: I made something by myself but i have one error tho : https://stackoverflow.com/q/76132558/21574220

Answer (score 1):

You error is happening where you are assigning to the `value` property of an element.  You are only doing that in one place in the code you posted:

```js
const totalPriceInput = document.querySelector("#total_price");
totalPriceInput.value = total.toFixed(2);
```

That error means when your code runs, `totalPriceInput` is `undefined` and it can't find the `value` property on `undefined`

So that mean that your `querySelector` is not getting anything back.  My guess is that it cannot find an element in your HTML with the ID `total_price` - you should double check this and make sure that this ID is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I changed that to total id which is correct but it still does not display total of checkout page in index page : heres current code of checkout page

```html
  <div class="total">
    <form action="index.html" class="total">
    <h3 style="text-align:center; display: none;">Subtotal: <br><span id="subtotal"></span></h3>
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">Total: <br><span id="total">$0</span></h3>
    <a href="index.html"><button type="submit" class="buy-btn" style="background-color: rgb(29, 4, 216);">Continue to purchase</button></a>
    <a href="index.html" onclick="alert('You will be redirected to the home page')"><button style="background-color: rgb(216, 4, 4);">Cancel</button></a>
  </div>
</form>
  <!--It does clear but wonder , make that you cant click on button if that function is done-->
</body>
<script>
  const cartItemsDiv = document.querySelector(".cart-items");
  const storedCartItem = localStorage.getItem("selectedItems");  
  let subtotal = 0;

  const continueButton = document.getElementById("buy-btn");
  const clearButton = document.getElementById("clear-button");

  function clearCartItems() {
  // Clear the HTML content of the cart-items div
  const cartItemsDiv = document.querySelector(".cart-items");
  cartItemsDiv.innerHTML = "";

  // Set the subtotal and total to $0
  const subtotalSpan = document.getElementById("subtotal");
  const totalSpan = document.getElementById("total");
  subtotalSpan.innerHTML = "";
  totalSpan.innerHTML = "$0";

  // Remove the selected items from localStorage
  localStorage.removeItem("selectedItems");

  alert("Added items will be cleared.");
  // Change the URL to the index page and prevent going to the checkout page
  window.location.href = "sproduct6.html";
  history.replaceState(null, "", window.location.href);

  // Update the UI
  document.getElementById("added-products").innerHTML = "You have no items in your cart!";
  document.getElementById("buy-btn").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("clear-button").style.display = "none";

   if (cartItemCount == 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("You have no items in your cart. Let's get back to product page.");
      window.location.href = ('sproduct6.html');
    }, 50); // 3 second delay 
    document.getElementById("added-products").innerHTML = "You have no items in your cart!";
    continueButton.style.display = "none";
    clearButton.style.display = "none";
    // Save the visibility state of the buttons
    localStorage.setItem("buttonsVisible", "false");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("added-products").innerHTML = "YOU ADDED THIS PRODUCTS";
  } 
}

if (storedCartItem) {
  const cartItem = JSON.parse(storedCartItem); // Parse the storedCartItem string into an array

  for (let i = 0; i < cartItem.length; i++) {
    const cartItemElement = document.createElement("div");  

    
    cartItemElement.innerHTML = `
        <hr />
        <h3>${cartItem[i].title}</h3>  
        <p>Price: ${cartItem[i].price}</p>
        <p>License: ${cartItem[i].license}</p>
        <img src="${cartItem[i].image}" width='30%'/><br>
        <audio controls style="width:50%;">
          <source src="${cartItem[i].audio}" type="audio/mp3"> 
        </audio>
        `;
    // ADD DELETE OPTION 

    cartItemsDiv.appendChild(cartItemElement);

    const price = Number(cartItem[i].price.replace("$", "")); // Parse price as a number and remove dollar sign
    subtotal += price;
    // MAKE REPLACE TITLE TO YOU HAVE NO ITEMS IN YOUR CART
  }

  const subtotalElement = document.querySelector("#subtotal");
  subtotalElement.textContent = `$${subtotal.toFixed(2)}`;

  const totalElement = document.querySelector("#total");
  const total = subtotal;
  totalElement.textContent = `$${total.toFixed(2)}`;
  const totalPriceInput = document.querySelector("#total");
  totalPriceInput.value = total.toFixed(2);
}

function passtotal(){
  var total = document.getElementById('total').value;
  var subtotal = document.getElementById('subtotal').value;
  localStorage.setItem("value", total);
  return false;
}
</script>
```

and this is my index page code :

```html
class="sr-root">
      <span id="total"></span>
      <div class="sr-main">
        <h1>Pay with a bunch of payment option</h1>

        <form id="payment-form" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    
          <div id="payment-element"></div>
    
          <button>Pay</button><!--Make functional-->
          <!--Make total price hidden and that total of this is same as in checkout and that its connected to ruby-->
          <div id="error-messages"></div>
        </form>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var getValue = localStorage.getItem("value");
      var value = JSON.parse(getValue);
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("value");
    </script>
```