# How to make sure that it redirects to certain url only when button is clicked javascript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

So I somehow built that It transfer total from checkout page to index page which is in this case payment page,But the is one problem;it automaticly goes to index page when going on checkout page but I want that it does that only when button is clicked.I tried to do something with addEventListener but it just goes on index.html? instead of something like index.html?total=320.00

heres checkout code:

```
  <div class="total">
    <form action="index.html" class="total">
    <h3 style="text-align:center; display: none;">Subtotal: <br><span id="subtotal"></span></h3>
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">Total: <br><span id="total">$0</span></h3>
    <a><button type="submit" class="buy-btn" style="background-color: rgb(29, 4, 216);">Continue to purchase</button></a>
    <a href="index.html" onclick="alert('You will be redirected to the home page')"><button style="background-color: rgb(216, 4, 4);">Cancel</button></a>
  </div>
</form>
  <!--It does clear but wonder , make that you cant click on button if that function is done-->
</body>
<script>
  const cartItemsDiv = document.querySelector(".cart-items");
  const storedCartItem = localStorage.getItem("selectedItems");  
  let subtotal = 0;

  const continueButton = document.getElementById("buy-btn");
  const clearButton = document.getElementById("clear-button");

function clearCartItems() {
  // Clear the HTML content of the cart-items div
  const cartItemsDiv = document.querySelector(".cart-items");
  cartItemsDiv.innerHTML = "";

  // Set the subtotal and total to $0
  const subtotalSpan = document.getElementById("subtotal");
  const totalSpan = document.getElementById("total");
  subtotalSpan.innerHTML = "";
  totalSpan.innerHTML = "$0";

  // Remove the selected items from localStorage
  localStorage.removeItem("selectedItems");

  alert("Added items will be cleared.");
  // Change the URL to the index page and prevent going to the checkout page
  window.location.href = "sproduct6.html";
  history.replaceState(null, "", window.location.href);

  // Update the UI
  document.getElementById("added-products").innerHTML = "You have no items in your cart!";
  document.getElementById("buy-btn").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("clear-button").style.display = "none";

   if (cartItemCount == 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("You have no items in your cart. Let's get back to product page.");
      window.location.href = ('sproduct6.html');
    }, 50); // 3 second delay 
    document.getElementById("added-products").innerHTML = "You have no items in your cart!";
    continueButton.style.display = "none";
    clearButton.style.display = "none";
    // Save the visibility state of the buttons
    localStorage.setItem("buttonsVisible", "false");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("added-products").innerHTML = "YOU ADDED THIS PRODUCTS";
  } 
}

if (storedCartItem) {
  const cartItem = JSON.parse(storedCartItem); // Parse the storedCartItem string into an array

  for (let i = 0; i < cartItem.length; i++) {
    const cartItemElement = document.createElement("div");  

    
    cartItemElement.innerHTML = `
        <hr />
        <h3>${cartItem[i].title}</h3>  
        <p>Price: ${cartItem[i].price}</p>
        <p>License: ${cartItem[i].license}</p>
        <img src="${cartItem[i].image}" width='30%'/><br>
        <audio controls style="width:50%;">
          <source src="${cartItem[i].audio}" type="audio/mp3"> 
        </audio>
        `;
    // ADD DELETE OPTION 

    cartItemsDiv.appendChild(cartItemElement);

    const price = Number(cartItem[i].price.replace("$", "")); // Parse price as a number and remove dollar sign
    subtotal += price;
    // MAKE REPLACE TITLE TO YOU HAVE NO ITEMS IN YOUR CART
  }

  const subtotalElement = document.querySelector("#subtotal");
  subtotalElement.textContent = `$${subtotal.toFixed(2)}`;

  const totalElement = document.querySelector("#total");
  const total = subtotal;
  totalElement.textContent = `$${total.toFixed(2)}`;

  // Add this line to redirect to index.html and pass the total as a query parameter
  window.location.href = 'index.html?total=' + total.toFixed(2);

  totalElement.textContent = `$${total.toFixed(2)}`;
  const totalPriceInput = document.querySelector("#total");
  totalPriceInput.value = total.toFixed(2);

  passtotal(); // Call the function to pass the total price to the index page

function passtotal(){
  var total = document.getElementById('total').value;
  var subtotal = document.getElementById('subtotal').value;
  localStorage.getItem("total", total);
  return false;
}
}
</script>
```

and heres index code

```
    <div class="sr-root">
      <span id="total"></span>
      <div class="sr-main">
        <h1>Pay with a bunch of payment option</h1>

        <form id="payment-form" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    
          <div id="payment-element"></div>
    
          <button>Pay</button><!--Make functional-->
          <!--Make total price hidden and that total of this is same as in checkout and that its connected to ruby-->
          <div id="error-messages"></div>
        </form>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      // get the value of the "total" parameter from the URL
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
      const total = urlParams.get("total");

      // set the text content of the span element to the total value
      const totalSpan = document.getElementById("total");
      totalSpan.textContent = total;
    </script>
```

Comment: This line doesn't seem to be in a function, so as soon as it is reached, it will go to the index page. `window.location.href = 'index.html?total=' + total.toFixed(2);` What were you expecting to happen with that line?

Comment: when I open the checkout page, it goes to the index page ,but I want it to go to the index only when I click on the continue button

Comment: Then you need to move the line that redirects the user to the function that is called when the continue button is clicked. Right now it's being invoked every time this page is run.

Comment: Can you paste me a code for that

Comment: You don't seem to have a submit function, but you form will automatically go to index.html when you submit it.

Comment: Your first example is invalid HTML script must go in the `<head>` or `<body` but not after the body close tag.

Comment: `document.getElementById("buy-btn");` element with this id does not exist in the HTML.  Due to all these syntax issues I am voting to close as caused by a syntax issue.

Answer (score 0):

several things to look into, based on your code

#1 wrong tag hierarchy

```
  <div class="total">
    <form ...>
    <h3 ...>
    <h3 ...>
    <a><button  ...></a>
    <a ...><button ...></a>
  </div>
</form>
```

you have the `<form>` inside the `<div>` but you close the tag outside... it should be, for example

```
  <div class="total">
    <form ...>
      <h3 ...>
      <h3 ...>
      <a><button  ...></a>
      <a ...><button ...></a>
    </form>
  </div>
```

#2 anchors surrounding buttons

you have

```
<a>
  <button type="submit" ...>Continue to purchase</button>
</a>
```

what are you trying to accomplish here? the `<a>` has a behavior already and you have a button inside it, that is of type `submit` so you are assigning another behavior, try to only have the `button` without surrounding it with an `anchor` so you can expect the normal button behavior

#3 how do form works?

you have a button of type `submit` that will submit the `form` that surrounds this tag, in this case, your `<form action="index.html" ...>` will be called and submitted, and it does that, it sends you to the `index.html` page as that's what you are asking it, and in a `GET` method (the default) meaning it will happened inputs to the URL instead of passing it in memory as `POST` does... but you do not have any inputs inside that `form` so it passes nothing, if you add an input, it will happend the value as you expect, like

```
  <div class="total">
    <form action="index.html">
      <h3 ...>
      <h3 ...>
      <button  ...>
      <a ...>
      <input type="hidden" name="total" value="200" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

it will send you to `index.html?total=200`

#4 your index form

your button, is well placed without any anchor tag, but is a simple button with the default behavior, as you just have it as `<button>Pay</button>` this will style as a button, and will behave as a submit

you also have it inside a form with the `POST` method, meaning you probably want it to send the data inside the `form` in a `POST` manner, for that we usually do one of 2 things (though there are more ways to accomplish the same)

1. the same as you did in the checkout form, we add the `type="submit"` and that will trigger the `form` that has this button, to be triggered
2. we add a javascript function or code that will run upon click, like `<button type="button" onclick="payNow()">Pay</button>` and in javascript it will run the function named `payNow` that you should write in the `script` code

we had to tell the `button` that we want to treat it as a "dumb" button by specifying the `type="button"` or you will use the default behavior, and that tends to be whatever the implementation of each browser (web or mobile) have implemented, maybe it will act as a `type="submit"` or it will act as `type="button"` you do not know, and that is why we tend to set the expectation by using te `type` attribute on button tags

I hope this 4 tips can help you get "unstuck" and continue your code, keep it up and don't give up, next month you will code this without even thinking about it

Comment: Yes, these and many more syntax issues.

Comment: I tried something by myself because I do not understand what are you saying : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76135741/why-when-changing-to-redirect-to-specific-url-it-suddently-says-null-for-total

Answer (score 0):

Too much code. Isolate the lines relating to your question. In any case, do not nest a button in an anchor element. Your anchor element's `href` should be programatically updated to include the query parameters that you want to pass, e.g.

```
<a href="https://google.com?dollars=12&cents=05">go</a>
```

You can store the amount in localStorage though as well provided you are opening a page in the same origin/domain name.

Use the `URL constructor`. `myurl.searchParams.append("dollar",12)`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams

Comment: I tried something by myself because I don't understand your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76135741/why-when-changing-to-redirect-to-specific-url-it-suddently-says-null-for-total